# High amperage power supply/powered hub

Tags: power, power-supply, media-server

I want to build a media center and I have got all I need except a power supply/hub to run it.

My components are:

- RPi 2 B (FAQ says 1.8A)
- External HDD (up to 1A as it is attached via 2 USB ports)
- External DVD (same = up to 1A)
- TV tuner (1 USB port = up to 0.5A)

All together it looks like **4.3A**.

I know I need to attach it via some powered hub as it could not run from Pi itself but I am struggling to find anything what would be sufficient.

The only thing I found is this: [Anidées 6 Port 50W High Power USB Hub (2.5A/Port)](http://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/accessories/usb-hubs/anidees-6-port-smart-ic-usb-charger-50-watt) but it seems a bit overkill.

I am based in EU. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Shopping suggestions are off topic here on the RPi Stack Exchange. But, just google 5v 2A USB adapter/power supply and for your powered hub, if it uses a barrel jack for power than Google "3A barrel jack power supply" I use both of those powder supplies on my Pi.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean overkill because there's too much juice available, you're right.

If your concern is that you'll spend too much money on power, I think you shouldn't:

1. The power supply potentially could draw 50 watts.  Potentially.  If
   it doesn't need all that power, it will use less.  Not completely percentual less, but less nonetheless.
2. Your calculation is that you need 21.5 watts.  But again, these are
   the manufacturers' specified maximum equipment draws.

Both facts in mind, I don't think this model is too bad.  It's well build, safe for all equipment (cfr. 'Powered by SMART IC') and it certainly won't eat 50 watts out of the mains grid so it's quite economic also.  Additionally it will last forever because it's not nearly operating at full capacity, and offers enough space for future expansions.

I'd say go for it.